# Is it possible to knit multiple .rmd files at once?

Tags: markdown, knitr

I've been running into a problem when I make a change to a specific page, for example, adding a css theme to the `YAML` document.

When I do this, I have to re-knit every `.rmd` file so that it can produce a new html document with the css theme included. Is there any way for me to knit every `.rmd` file at once? Or do I have to re-knit every single `.rmd` for my website?

**Update:**

To solve this problem you can use the following line of code:

```
rmarkdown::render_site()
```

This assumes that all your `.rmd` files are in the same directory. See [**here**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmarkdown/rmarkdown.pdf) on page 52 for more information.

Just in case anyone reads this again, I wanted to mention `blogdown` since this is a popular package for creating blogs with R Markdown. See [**here**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/blogdown/blogdown.pdf) and [**here**](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Just render all the .rmd files.

Comment: Is there a specific command I can use? Currently, I have to open each doc and knit it to HTML. Gets pretty tedious with 30+ documents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To render a list of documents, first you need to put the document names in a variable.  One way to do that is

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "[.]rmd$")
```

This assumes your files are named `*.rmd`.  If they are `*.Rmd`, modify accordingly.

Then to render them all, just use a `for` loop:

```
for (f in files) rmarkdown::render(f)
```

This assumes you have the headers all set up to define the output you want.  Set the `output_format` argument to `render()` if you want to override that.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out `render`, I was able to do what I wanted using the following command: `rmarkdown::render_site()`